# The equation of the plane in five-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a five-dimensional space. There are three points (coordinates) and need to find the equation of a plane through 3 points. How to do this?

$$B(1,1,0,1,1)$$
$$C(8,7,3,1,4)$$
$$D(1,0,-1,3,-3)$$

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're expecting.  Planes have nice, neat equations in 3d because you can phrase them in terms of a dot product with the normal.  Planes in 5d do not have normal vectors but whole 3d spaces that are normal to them.  Contrast the equation of a plane in 3d against the equation of a line, which is usually done in parametric for good reasons.  What kind of equation are you expecting for an answer here?

Comment: @Muphrid, The equation of the plane in three-dimensional subspace of five-dimensional space

Comment: Okay, but there's no unique three dimensional subspace of the five dimensional space which contains that plane. So I'm still not sure what you're expecting to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your affine plane consists of the following points: $$\{B+a\vec{BC}+b\vec{BD}:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate barycentric co-ordinates, which are homogeneous.

The basic equation is $(b+c+d)P=bB+cC+dD$ for a point $P$ in the plane of $B,C,D$ for your problem - but the scheme invites generalisation to other dimensions.